# Vanilla Javascript how to toggle closest hidden element

Tags: javascript

I have multiple text-blocks where each contains a "Read more" button.

See this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e4awgxh5/1/) (Updated)

```js
let toggleBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-toggle");
let hiddenArea = document.querySelector(".hidden");

toggleBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (hiddenArea.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      hiddenArea.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      hiddenArea.classList.add("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="text-blocks">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" style="display:none">
      <p>This is some hidden text</p>
    </div>

    <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more
         <svg class="caret stroke-current transition-transform ease-in-out duration-200" width="18" height="11" viewBox="0 0 18 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M2 2L9.00104 9.5L16 2" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square"/>
         </svg>  
        </button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-blocks">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" style="display:none">
      <p>This is some hidden text</p>
    </div>

    <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more
         <svg class="caret stroke-current transition-transform ease-in-out duration-200" width="18" height="11" viewBox="0 0 18 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M2 2L9.00104 9.5L16 2" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square"/>
        </svg>  
        </button>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-blocks">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>

    <div class="hidden" style="display:none">
      <p>This is some hidden text</p>
    </div>

    <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more
         <svg class="caret stroke-current transition-transform ease-in-out duration-200" width="18" height="11" viewBox="0 0 18 11" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M2 2L9.00104 9.5L16 2" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="square"/>
        </svg>  
        </button>
  </div>
</section>
```

This doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: You can use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method.

Comment: Delegate the click events of the buttons to the `section` elements: `sections.forEach(section => section.addEventListener('click', e => {if (e.target.tagName !== 'BUTTON') {return;} e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');})`. I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x48uLc2h/) based on your fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would delegate from the closest container of the sections

I would also give the divs a classname that is not disappearing - here I added class of `toggle`

Lastly I use closest to get the parent section in case you want to move the button around, making a sibling no longer a previousElementSibling

Also let's change the text of the button since we can

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", e => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("button"); // in case you have something in the button
  if (tgt && tgt.classList.contains("btn-toggle")) { // did we find the element?
    const hidden = tgt.closest("section")
      .querySelector(".toggle") // the div that can be toggled
      .classList.toggle("hidden"); // returns true or false for hidden or not
    tgt.textContent = hidden ? "Read more ⮟" : "Read less ⮝";
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section class="text-blocks">
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>This is some text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle hidden">
        <p>This is some hidden text</p>
      </div>

      <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more ⮟
        </button>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="text-blocks">
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>This is some text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle hidden">
        <p>This is some hidden text</p>
      </div>

      <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more ⮟
        </button>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="text-blocks">
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>This is some text</p>
      </div>

      <div class="toggle hidden">
        <p>This is some hidden text</p>
      </div>

      <button class="btn-toggle">
         Read more ⮟
        </button>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats really nice! I will accept that answer :-) What if I want to add some arrows? Please check my updated question

Comment: @ST80 I added text arrows. The SVG is ugly and hard to use, but if you make an UP svg I can toggle between them if you want

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to handle each element if you use
[event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Furthermore, the `style` attribute doesn't make sense if you already use a `hidden` class. You can use `classList.toggle` to set/remove the `hidden` class.

In the snippet I moved the button inside `div.toggle`. The handler either shows or hides the `p`. The advantage is that the button text can now be manipulated using css only.

You can do a lot with css only. Here is a [simplified version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gv2m6a?file=index.js) of the snippet.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target
  if (origin.closest('.btn-toggle')) {
    return origin.closest('.toggle').classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden p {
  display: none;
}

.toggle.hidden button:after {
  content: 'Read more \25bc';
}

.toggle button:after {
  content: 'Read less \25b2';
}
```

```html
<section class="text-blocks">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden toggle">
      <button class="btn-toggle"></button>
      <p>This is some hidden text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="text-blocks">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>This is some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden toggle">
      <button class="btn-toggle"></button>
      <p>This is some hidden text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Honestly, I did not see your code until after posting this answer. 'Use "event delegation"' is pretty much my standard answer in cases like this.

Comment: What is the purpose of `return` in an event handler?

Comment: For more complex event delegation it makes sense to return, to avoid unnecessary or unwanted code execution. It's my standard operation procedure. Here is [an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-dbn5wb?file=UIFactory.js) of that.

Comment: I edited the answer to give an alternative (demonstrate a different method to change the button text ;)

Comment: @ST80 Added arrows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to examine the event object, which passed to the event handler.

```
toggleBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const target = e.target; // that will be the button which was clicked, since the event handler was attached to it
    const div = target.parentNode // the wrapping <div>
    // using the div as context will yield the hidden area
    // »for that button«
    const hidden = div.querySelector('.hidden');

    if (hidden) { /* logic to show here */ }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, please delegate and use closest or sibling

Comment: @mplungjan The target element is a sibling, closest is not useful in this case.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, since we can move the sibling around. Either use sibling OR `target.closest('section').querySelector('.hidden')` - but I would change the class to something that can be found even when it is hidden

Comment: @mplungjan closest won't work in your example. Either you've misunderstood the question or you don't understand closest.... EDIT: I stand corrected.... :)